# Software and hardware recommendation for painting

Tags: software-recommendation, drawing-tablet

I've written some books for my kids and now I want to digitally paint some illustrations.

I would like touch sensitive tablet which includes a screen so I can see what I'm painting without having to look up at a monitor.

Ideally this tablet would support windows.

I'm also looking for software that is designed specifically for digital painting i.e. I don't want a photo editor!

What do the group mind recommend?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Hardware recommendation are off-topic here. Sorry about that.

Comment: This is also such a personal experience that even decent recommendations may not suit *your* painting style. Best thing to do is go to a store and *try* hardware when possible.

Comment: I'd be looking at an iPad with  Pencil 2. Windows support is OK, if not as good as on Mac. There are a myriad drawing/painting apps for it - a randomly-googled list here - https://www.creativebloq.com/digital-art/art-on-the-ipad-1232669

Comment: If you want simple drawing/painting software with support for pressure sensitive graphics tablets, I can recommend MyPaint and Krita. They're free and open source. Krita is the more advanced of the two. As for graphics tablets, I don't know of any that don't work on Windows. I think you'd be hard pressed to find one that doesn't.

Comment: Painting and photoeditting features go hand in hand. Photoeditting is just simply paint engine lite, and any competent pixel painting application is going to do some level of photoediting

Answer (score 1):

> I don't want a photo editor

Sorry I am not starting from the beginning. But I do not know why you are discarding something. I am not sure if you are really aware of the differences.

For example. Is Photoshop a good program for digital paint? Of course... Is photoshop a good program for photo editing? Of course... So are you discarding Photoshop just because?

In my opinion, you should focus on what you really want.

> designed specifically for digital painting

sounds specific but in reality, it is not.

Here is a similar question regarding free software that can be used for digital paint [Free software suggestion use with drawing tablet](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/90504/free-software-suggestion-use-with-drawing-tablet) but almost all of them can be used as a photo editor.

If you really need a program for digital paint, this is "I want a program that can simulate watercolor transparency", or "I want a program that simulates a brushstroke of oily paint", then the list is probably narrowed to some programs.

Corel Painter Is probably the king: https://www.painterartist.com to simulate most of the paint techniques.

Another great option is Rebelle https://www.escapemotions.com/products/rebelle/about?//products/rebelle/index.php

If you realize that you do not need something that specific, then consider the list I linked for free software that can make a good solution in most cases.

(You also need to differentiate if you really meant "Paint" because there are some other software with drawing in mind, for example for manga style)

---

Regarding the hardware, It is better if you make a systematic search viewing youtube reviews. Start searching some parameters like:

Wacom vs Huion vs XP Pen Artist, which currently are the 3 brands that have some reputation on monitor tablets. Wacom is the most trusted brand and now has some entry-level monitors.

- Look for color rendition
- Size
- Responsiveness
- Parallelism

Comment: The only reason I was discounting photo editors such as Photoshop elements was because I'd been told that there was significant complex set up for brushes and how they interact with tablets!

Comment: Oh, Ok. Yes, there are some small pieces of software for simple photo editing that would not be suitable for painting. But all of the list I mentioned will work fine.